# Execute code when receiving SUSPEND and APMRESUME messages

Tags: perl, windows-7, message

How do I "catch" a SUSPEND and a APMRESUME messages in windows using perl?

The objective is to make a program where it is a good idea to warn the server about the user disconnection whenever it's possible.

I already tried to search in many places how to do this. I can only find how to do in .net using/or C# but I can't find for perl.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean the *Windows Advanced Power Management* API? The closest I can find is [`Sys::Apm`](https://metacpan.org/module/Sys%3a%3aApm), but that provides only for fetching current status values and will not handle events

Since ACPI has superseded APM I don't think a module is likely to be written that does what you want, but perhaps you could use [`Win32::API`](https://metacpan.org/module/Win32%3a%3aAPI) to write a Perl interface to the relevant DLL

I'm afraid that's all I can suggest

Comment: I don't have knowledge to write a dll properly... Is there a way to get a dll to handle that or somewhere where I can learn properly how to do one?

Comment: Windows APIs are supplied by Microsoft in DLL files. They are intended to be used from C# or Visual Basic, but Win32::API allows you to interface to them from Perl. Presumably the documentation you have found regarding C# explains this